# How to find all class names or ids from a CSS file that contains a background image using Regular expression and PHP?

Tags: php, css, regex

I want to get the class name or the ID from a text using regular expression with PHP.

For Instance:

```
.vc_custom_1547091583528{
    margin-bottom:40px!important;
    padding-top:7rem!important;
    padding-bottom:1rem!important;
    background:#092746 url(http://icoachu.us/wp- 
    content/uploads/2016/12/princeton.jpg?id=957)!important;
    background-position:center!important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat!important;
    background-size:cover!important
}
```

This is css and the output should be:

```
array(0=>".vc_custom_1547091583528");
```

and also

```
array(0 => "http://icoachu.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/princeton.jpg?id=957")
```

So they will be two different functions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should not be too hard to parse such rules

Comment: `(?:\(['"]?)(.*?)(?:['"]?\))` will return `array(0 => "http://icoachu.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/princeton.jpg?id=957")`. Now I need the other one.

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: @NicoHaase I only need a regular expression instead of a whole library for the task. I am not familiar with the regular expressions but I know it can be done using one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the right answer. The regular expression can be made more smarter and short but right now this one works just fine.

```
([.#][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*?){[a-zA-Z0-9~;:#! _-]*\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)[a-zA-Z0-9~;:#! _-]*}
```